# ASP.NET MVC 4 file upload fails with <button>

Tags: html, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

In creating a file upload feature using ASP.NET MVC 4 I experienced an issue where the POSTed file is null in my Action

**Razor** (results in null file variable in action)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Trip", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true);
}
```

**Razor** (works fine)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Trip", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true);
}
```

**Action**

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
         //The action executes but file is null when using <button>
}
```

I have read the [often cited article by Phill Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) and the only difference between our implementations is that he uses an `<input type="submit" />` element where as I use `<button type="submit">`. To my understanding, both of these HTML elements will post in the same fashion. I am using a `<button>` to apply CSS styles to the button.

Any ideas why the `<input>` posts the file fine but the `<button>` implementation doesn't?

Comment: Both are working ok for me - are you sure there are no other differences when you're using `input` vs. `button`? Maybe some javascript attached to the event handler that might funk up the form?

Comment: I don't recall which browser I was using and will update the question with more info as I gather it.